# bootstrap 3 column responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

how do I achive this in bootstrap. I have a 3 column and want to stay 3 column be it on mobile or desktop.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Example - 3 column div</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">First</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Second</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Third</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

on desktop

```
First | Second | Third
```

on mobile it become like this

```
First | Second  
| Third
```

I want to achieve this on desktop and mobile

```
First | Second | Third
```

Here are the fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/y28ugzp6/

Comment: Change classes to `col-xs-4 col-sm-4` - actually you could just do `col-xs-4` as this will then work for every size - also, you might want to read what these classes actually mean and then you would have been able to answer yourself easily I think

Comment: just use `col-xs-4` for every column.

Comment: xs-6 means on extra small you are taking 50% width , and outer div width is always 100% so it will devided into 2 parts automatically so xs-4 is fine for u

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set all div's classes to `col-xs-4`:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">First</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Second</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Third</div>
```

Comment: Add above divs inside <div class="row">

Answer (score 5):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
 
  <p>You can define it using md,sm and xs</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">Java</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">PHP</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:lavender;">JQuery</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use one class `col-xs-4`.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Example - 3 column div</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 ">First</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">Second</div>
          <div class="col-xs-4">Third</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better is #Arkej.

But
You can also do like this:

```
<div class="container">
        <div>
            <h1>Example - 3 column div</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">First</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Second</div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">Third</div>
           </div>
        </div>
</div>
```